# Asp.Net OData V4: How can I get exceptions to bubble up to a global handler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am relatively new to Asp.Net OData.   What I have realized is that the `ODataMediaTypeFormatter` logs exceptions like JSON deserialization issues and does not throw an exception.  So I created a `ModelValidationFilterAttribute` and enabled it globally through HttpConfiguration.

```
public class ModelValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response =
                actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that things like `System.InsufficientExecutionStackException` also get sent down to the client using this validation filter.

I want model validation state to be sent to the client when there is an error in the model format/data.  For code exceptions, I would prefer that the exception just bubble up to a global handler where I can log, check the exception type, and respond to the client accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to create an exception filter like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        }
    }
}
```

then you can control how to respond to the client. In the above example, it send 501 to the client.

References:

1. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling
2. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling

Comment: Thank you.  This is useful as now I can handle the exception.  It appears that exception filters run before action filters.   However, is it normal in MVC and/or WebApi for an exception, especially SystemException types like InsufficientExecutionStackException, to not trigger the Application_Error event (i.e. in Global.asax.cs)?  I have not been able to catch it in that event.

Comment: Added 2 references, which may help you.

Comment: The references you added definitely helped.   It still seems crazy that something like a deserialization error would wind up captured in ModelState rather than throwing an exception outright.  But that's the nature of the beast at the moment I suppose. So in summary we have IExceptionFilter, IExceptionHandler, IExceptionLogger and sometimes Application_Error, with the exception not necessary bubbling up if one of these (excluding the logger) does not handle the exception.